# nest properties in properties (in properties) (ant to maven migration)

Tags: java, maven, ant, properties

We used ant for building (a huge) project and (because of legacy reasons) we nested properties inside property files quite deeply.

(inside build.xml for instance)

```
<ant dir="${object.build.dir}" target="deploy" />
```

(inside some property file:)

```
object.build.dir=${base.dir}
```

(inside some other property file (sometimes even the same)):

```
base.dir=${env}/some/dir
```

Then, because ant isn't that recent anymore we are moving to maven now, which would be quite a nightmare...

The question is: how do you read properties that are the result of nesting properties inside properties for as far as 5 levels deep sometimes...

(as a test)

filters/top_level.properties:

```
env=test
```

filters/test/mid_level.properties:

```
specific=spec
```

filters/top_level.properties could also read (for another environment):

```
env=prod
```

and so filters/prod/mid_level.properties:

```
specific=spock
```

The question boils down to this:

How do I read/use a 'specific' property which is defined inside a property file for which the path is defined in yet another property file?)
(And this kinds of nesting all over the place?)

Also, this doesn't concern 'resources' (these are also involved but not the main issue, resources are properties that are used by the application, the properties I talk about are properties that are used only at build time to specify how the build happens)

I found an answer but if there is a better one I'd be glad to choose that as best answer...

S.

Comment: Your properties look like a setup for different environments which is never a good idea to use properties for neither in Ant nor in Maven....May be you could take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin...Furthermore I assume that you build each time for each property which means for dev, prod etc. This will not work in Maven...just build once and produce all the needed output in one run...

Comment: hey, thanks, I'll surely take a look at it, S.

Answer (score 0):

In maven you have the [properties:read-project-properties](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html) plugin.

If you use it like this nested properties will not get inserted in descended ones:
(maven will still complain it doesn't find the "filters/${env}/mid_level.properties" property file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution1</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>filters/top_level.properties</file>
                            <file>filters/${env}/mid_level.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But if you separate executions like this (+ echoing the value of 'specific':)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution1</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>filters/top_level.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution2</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>filters/${env}/mid_level.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>echo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <echos>
                        <echo>Animal: ${specific}</echo>
                    </echos>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

output with env=prod:

```
[INFO] --- maven-echo-plugin:0.1:echo (default) @ test ---
[INFO] Animal: spock
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.663 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-13T21:32:30+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/164M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Problem solved :)

You 'just' need to have as many property executions as depth of nesting + refactoring the properties to have them in strata but appart from that this problem is 'easily' solved...